# Get multiple unique random rows for tags in MySql from one reference table

Tags: mysql

I have one table where references between tags and items are stored in my database, in the form

```
id - tagID - itemID
1  -  1    -   1
2  -  2    -   1
3  -  1    -   2
4  -  3    -   2
5  -  4    -   2
```

etc

I have as input the current itemID, and I want to select one other random item ID for each tag this item has.

The obvious way is to run one query to select the tags of this item, and then one query for each of those tags to select a different itemID for each tag.

For example for the itemID "1"

```
SELECT tagID FROM mytags WHERE itemID=1
```

and then foreach tagID "X"

```
SELECT itemID FROM mytags WHERE tagID= "X" AND itemID!=1
```

But if an item has 10 tags, this will result in 11 queries just for this part of my application.

I am trying to find a way to run a single SQL to get the same results.

A good start is the following

```
SELECT tagID, itemID
FROM `mytags`
WHERE tagID IN ( SELECT tagID
                 FROM `mytags`
                 WHERE itemID =1 )
AND itemID !=1
```

But this returns all the other rows for the tags of this item, while I want only one of them.

Anyone has any great ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you only want one of them, why don't you add a `LIMIT 1` to your query?

Comment: Because "Limit 1" will give me one item from one tag. I want one item for each tag.

Answer (score 0):

As most allways with random picks, there are quite a few arguments **not** to do this in a combined query: You will have to `ORDER BY RAND()` which is a performance killer. My suggestion is to either work in your surrounding language, or create a stired procedure:

- Declare a cursor for `SELECT DISTINCT tagID FROM`mytags`WHERE itemID=1`
- Loop this cursor doing
- `SELECT MAX(id) INTO maxid FROM`mytags`WHERE tagID=current_tag_from_cursor AND itemID<>1`
- `SELECT itemID FROM`mytags`WHERE tagID=current_tag_from_cursor AND itemID<>1 AND id>CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*maxid) AS UNSIGNED)`

Yes, you do a lot of queries.
Yes this gives still way better performance than `ORDER BY RAND()` on a table bigger than a few thousand rows

Comment: The ORDER BY RAND() I have avoided it by working in php indeed (By getting the first item over X, where X I calculate in php). I will study how/if I can work with a stored procedure in my environment.